# PostgreSQL installation as a user on Cygwin, database server setup

Tags: postgresql, cygwin, database-connection, relational-database, database-server

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL on Cygwin as a user and i'm getting stuck on the part where I have to create a database server, after i execute the pg_ctl command, it just prints "server starting" and runs in the foregorund indefinitely, here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

http://postimg.org/image/oh7ucgt9h/

Im generally a beginner to databases so any pointers would be great.

Comment: Did you look at the log? Rather than a screenshot by the way it's usually better to copy and paste the content of the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Chances you are hanging allocating shared memory.  Please go with the native Windows build instead.  It is far easier to manage.

However if you insist, make sure the ipc-daemon is running before you run PostgreSQL.  This will probably solve your problem.

You could run:

```
ipc-daemon --install-as-service
net start ipc-daemon
```

And this should do it.